# How to access Screen Narrator setting from Xbox UWP app?

Tags: uwp, xbox-one, ott

I have a javascript UWP app running on Xbox One for a long time now, but recently we've been asked to implement TTS (text to speech) for the platform. The thing is, first we need to know if the Screen Reader setting is enabled. How can I access this setting from the API within my javascript application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[UWP App Diagnostics](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/)** to get the system running processes.

Enumerate running processes via [ProcessDiagnosticInfo's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.processdiagnosticinfo?view=winrt-22621#methods) Method `GetForProcesses()`, check if `Narrator.exe` is in the list.

> Gets a list of `ProcessDiagnosticInfo` objects for all running processes
> that are accessible to the caller.

Here is the official [UWP sample TaskMinitor](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) for your reference.

[image]